# Crystal Reports Runtime & Redistributable

Tags: crystal-reports, asp.net-2.0

Is there a difference between these two things. I am trying to move some reports from a local server to a dev server and I know that we have installed the redist on the dev server, but am still having problems getting the report to run. Is the runtime separate I come accross different sites mentioning both things but havent been able to tell if they are talking about the same thing

*Edit - posting code to see if as dotjoe suggested I have incorrectly labled my report path. the database connection is returned from a method to a string array reportString so that is what that array is.

```
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer2" runat="server" 
    AutoDataBind="True" Height="50px" Width="350px" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True"                                                                         ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="~/images/reportViwerImages"/>



    ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            myConnectionInfo.ServerName = reportString[1];
            myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = reportString[0];
            myConnectionInfo.UserID = reportString[2];
            myConnectionInfo.Password = reportString[3];

            string ReportPath = Server.MapPath("../../mdReports/CrystalReport.rpt");
            CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = ReportPath;

            ParameterField field1 = new ParameterField();
            ParameterDiscreteValue val1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            val1.Value = hiddenFieldReportNumber.ToString();
            field1.CurrentValues.Add(val1);
            SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);


    private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo)
    {
        TableLogOnInfos myTableLogOnInfos = CrystalReportViewer2.LogOnInfo;
        foreach (TableLogOnInfo myTableLogOnInfo in myTableLogOnInfos)
        {
            myTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmmm, are the paths setup the same on both machines? I ask because "load report failed" error usually has to do with path. AFAIK runtime and the redist are the same. Do you have a link to what you installed?

Comment: I am using crystal reports that was included with vs 2008 and the redist i installed i dont remember where i got it from but they are always named the same over the multiple sites i found it on. CRRedist2008_x86.zip i will post some code and edit my original post to see if that shines any light on the problem.

Comment: dotjoe figured it out. I was missing a folder in my server path if you form your comment as a answer i will accept it thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you have not load the report from the given Path.

Please see below [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691450%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)